# Sharepoint Workflow sends request to invalid port

Tags: workflow, 2016, workflow-manager

I have the problem with starting Workflow on Sharepoint 2016, when I'm starting the Workflow I got an error

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

I noticed that HTTP request is sending to port 2093 - which is old port of the application, when Im simply delete the old port from the URL I'm getting the data from the Sharepoint without any problem.

What should I do to stop workflow sending a request to the bad port - Did I miss something?

Comment: Check this **[Register-SPworkflowservice unable to connect to the remote service at Workflow Manager 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/register-spworkflowservice-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-service/)**

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's not the problem with workflow manager himself, that's working ok on different sites, but Workflow Manager wants to send request to webapplication which is not exist.